# Mir gefällt etw. an dir/ mich stört etw. an dir/ usw…

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, sociolinguistics, language

Es geht wieder um die Verwendung der Präposition *an*, aber dieses Mal in Verbindung mit Verben wie *gefallen*, *mögen*, *stören*…

Wie zum Beispiel bei folgenden Sätzen:

> An dir gefällt mir deine Stimme.

> Mich stört an dir dein Musikgeschmack.

> Ich mag an ihr ihre Denkweise.

Ich weiß, dass es sich bei Sätzen mit Präpositionen u.a um Präpositionalobjekte, um adverbiale Bestimmungen oder um Attribute handeln kann.

**Nun möchte ich gerne wissen, welche Funktion die Präposition *an* in den oben genannten Beispielen hat.**

Auf die Schnelle denke ich, dass es sich um lokale adverbiale Bestimmungen handelt, denn *an* gibt an, an wem du etwas magst, oder an wem dich etwas stört.

**Ausserdem könnte ich statt *an* auch die Präposition *von* verwenden, um dasselbe zu sagen, oder?**

Beispielsweise:

> Von ihr mag ich ihre Stimme.

> Von ihm stört mir sein Musikgeschmack.

Comment: Hmm... isn't the "Von ihr mag ich.." usage colloquial?

Answer (score 1):

##### Sie setzt den Rahmen der Aussage

Nehmen wir den Satz

> An dir gefällt mir deine Stimme.

Wortwörtlich sagt die Präposition aus, dass der Ort des Gefallens "an dir" ist. Aber wo soll deine Stimme noch sein, wenn nicht "an dir"? Diese adverbiale Bestimmung hat also *keinen* Informationsgehalt.

Sie dient vielmehr dazu, das Thema bzw. den Rahmen der Aussage festzulegen:
Wir reden über Eigenschaften *von dir* und von *diesen* Eigenschaften gefällt mir deine Stimme. Deswegen funktioniert es gut mit Vergleichen:

> An dir gefällt mir deine Stimme am besten.

Genau deswegen ist "an dir" auch immer (bis auf Sätze mit spezieller Intonation) vor der Eigenschaft, von der die Rede ist, und ist ganz häufig auch im Vorfeld.

Andere Präpositionen, wie z.B. "von" oder "bei" können diese Rolle auch erfüllen. "gefallen", "stören", etc. sind Verben, bei denen die Eigenschaft das Subjekt ist  und die Person mit dem Eindruck das Dativobjekt ist. Bei Verben, wo das andersherum ist, wie z.B. "lieben", funktioniert das auch:

> An ihrem Mann liebt sie nichts als sein Geld.

Comment: 'Aber wo soll deine Stimme noch sein, wenn nicht "an dir"?' - der konkrete Satz ist natürlich etwas tautologisch. "An dir gefällt mir die Stimme." klingt genauso natürlich, und da hat das "an dir" durchaus einen Informationsgehalt.

Answer (score -1):

In den genannten Beispielsätzen haben die Präpositionen "an" und "von" eine ähnliche Funktion. Sie werden verwendet, um das Objekt oder die Eigenschaft zu beschreiben, die dir an der Person gefällt, dich stört oder die du magst.

In den Sätzen:

> - An dir gefällt mir deine Stimme.
> - Mich stört an dir dein Musikgeschmack.
> - Ich mag an ihr ihre Denkweise.

ist "an" eine Präposition, die verwendet wird, um die Person zu kennzeichnen, auf die sich die Aussage bezieht. Es handelt sich um eine lokale adverbiale Bestimmung, die angibt, auf wen oder was sich die Meinung oder das Gefühl bezieht.

Es ist auch möglich, die Präposition "von" anstelle von "an" zu verwenden, um dieselbe Bedeutung auszudrücken. Die Sätze würden dann wie folgt lauten:

> - Von dir gefällt mir deine Stimme.
> - Mich stört von dir dein Musikgeschmack.
> - Ich mag von ihr ihre Denkweise.

In diesem Kontext haben sowohl "an" als auch "von" die Funktion, das Bezugsperson oder das Bezugselement zu kennzeichnen, auf das sich die Aussage bezieht. Es gibt jedoch manchmal einen leichten Unterschied in der Nuance zwischen den beiden Präpositionen, und die Wahl kann von der persönlichen Vorliebe oder dem regionalen Sprachgebrauch abhängen.

Comment: Vielleicht gibt es hier regionale Unterschiede, aber für mich hören sich die drei Beispielsätze mit "von" allesamt merkwürdig an. Da gehört meinem Gefühl nach "an" hin, oder vielleicht "bei", aber auf keinen Fall "von".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, das sehe ich genauso.

Comment: Das "von" ist hier deshalb falsch (nicht nur ungewöhnlich) , weil es eine Auswahlmenge angibt: "von A, B und C habe ich am liebsten B". "von Dir" enthält aber nur ein Element ("Du") und dehalb ist das Unsinn. Stünde mehr als eine Möglichkeit zur Auswahl ("Von den Nasen von A, B oder C mag ich am liebsten die von C"), dann ist das "von" sinnvoll.